# get html element under another element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with some cells. I also have a simple `div` with `position: absolute` and with an alpha background and with `z-index: 1`. So, this `div` lays on the table. In my code I catch the `mousemove` event and get the current cell. But with this `div` on top of the table, I can't get the underlying cell. Is there some way to get triggered the underlying `mousemove` event on a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically needs to set the css property **pointer-events** to none for div

for more info can refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @derstauner I am glad that fix helped you!!